# select2 control not working inside ngrepeat Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-1.2

My html looks like

```
<tbody >                                
    <tr  ng-repeat="test in List">
        <td>
        <select class="dropDownCtrl" ng-model="test.rptManager" id="rptManager{{$index}}"          name="rptManager{{$index}}" style="width: 100%;"  ng-options="rm.code as rm.code+'/'+rm.desc for rm in mgrList"   >                              
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and my script looks like

```
$ ( document ).ready ( function ( ) {
    $ ( '.dropDownCtrl').select2 ( {
        width : 'resolve' ,
        allowClear : true ,         
        dropdownAutoWidth : true 
    } );

    
} );
```

I am stuck with this, Thanks in advance. Select2-container-open not calling while clicking dropdown arrow it looks like the arrow in disable state.